# Shadow effect to UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, scrollview

I have a silly question Is there any way to give shadow effect to the `UIScrollView` likewise we do in `UIButtons`.

Any help is appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a shadow to any view by settings the `shadowOpacity`, `shadowRadius`, `shadowOffset`, `shadowColor`, and `shadowPath` properties of the view's `layer`.